# C++ char single quotes vs double quotes & memory inner workings

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, memory-address

I want to know what the program does memory-wise during runtime as it comes across the following:

```
char chr = 'a';
char chrS[] = "a";
cout << "Address: " << &chr << endl;
cout << "Address: " << &chrS << endl;
```

This produces the following:

```
Address: a�c�3�
Address: 0x7fff33936280
```

Why can't I get the memory address of "chr"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `&chr` yields a `char*` (implicit addition of `const` here) and `cout` assumes that it is a string and therefore null terminated, which it is not.

However, `&chrS` yields a `char(*)[]`, which will not decay to a `const char*` and therefore will be output through the `operator<<(std::ostream&, const void*)` overload, which prints the address.

If you want this behaviour for a `const char*` you will have to perform an explicit cast. The fact that there is no difference between a C-string and a pointer to a single character is one of the primary flaws of C-strings.

Comment: also consider the fact that the terminal may not support an appropriate charset for representing all your output correctly; under some OS this is a very common issue.

Comment: @user827992: It does not matter whether the terminal could potentially represent all output, since he is dumping memory that is not a null terminated string and that will cause undefined behavior --basically anything can happen.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas i was referring to the way the output is reproduced in the question, sometime can be misleading, since we are talking about char(s) i think that it's important to stress this point.

Comment: A C string is a null-terminated sequence of characters. A `char*` can point to a string, but it isn't a string.

Comment: The type system treats them as identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cout << "Address: " << hex << (long)(&chr) << endl;
```

Otherwise, when it gets the pointer to a char, it thinks you're giving it a string and tries to print it as one.

Comment: Won't work on some 64-bit systems. And even when it does work it will print the address in decimal instead of hex.

Comment: I had figured the OP could format it as desired, but I agree that hex is generally what you want.
I would have thought that it would be 32-bit systems where this might not work. Is there anything you could cast it to that would actually work everywhere?

Comment: A 64-bit system will have 64-bit pointers but still might have 32-bit longs - Windows is that way for example. You might find a type such as INT_PTR which is sized to hold either a pointer or an int.

Comment: I hadn't realized that Windows held on to a 32-bit long on 64-bit systems. It seems like there's probably not any solution here that will work on all systems.

Comment: @David: `INT_PTR`, `UINT_PTR` are designed for exactly this purpose, as Mark said.  Also, `long long` would work on _most_ systems, but is not suggested.